# 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'count' compiler error

Tags: swift, ios8

First of all, I tried using JSON Serialization in the following code and I tried looping through each items available in the array. However, it must be type casting that I am missing something. Here is the snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
    let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:      
    NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as
            NSDictionary

    var items = [[String:String]()]
    var item: AnyObject
    var authorDictionary: AnyObject

    for var i = 0; i < jsonResult["items"].count; i++ {

                items.append([String:String]())
                items[i]["content"] = item["content"] as? NSString
                items[i]["title"] = item["title"] as? NSString
                items[i]["publishedDate"] = item["published"] as? NSString
                authorDictionary = item["author"]  as NSDictionary
                items[i]["author"] = item["displayName"] as? NSString

     }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. The *compiler* error you've got can be resolved by casting the object to a type which does have a `.count` property. also, your `items` array always will have an empty dictionary since you initialize it with one, and you always append a new one to the end of the array upon every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your error, change this:

```
jsonResult["items"]
```

to this:

```
(jsonResult["items"] as! NSArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i am not with my xcode here, but looking the code i think in something about this.

```
let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:      
NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as
        NSDictionary

var items = [[String:String]()]
var item: AnyObject
var authorDictionary: AnyObject
if let itemsFromJson:NSArray = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray
{

    for itemJson in itemsFromJson {

            items.append([String:String]())
            items[i]["content"] = itemJson["content"] as? NSString
            items[i]["title"] = itemJson["title"] as? NSString
            items[i]["publishedDate"] = itemJson["published"] as? NSString
            authorDictionary = itemJson["author"]  as NSDictionary
            items[i]["author"] = itemJson["displayName"] as? NSString

    }

 }
```